# Validation does not work for a sign up form however there are no errors in my code?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I wanted to get better a js code so I decided to make a submit form using HTML ans js code respectively.I made thr form and validations but when I run it the validation don't work and instead send me to the results.html page which outputs everything the user used to sign up.[image]

I tried taking code out from the js file but that didn't work then I took code from the HTML file but still nothing. I am a beginner so how would I problem solve this? Should I start from scratch? Thank you again.

Comment: Could you pleas try to create [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with actual code in your question? Are you sure your JavaScript file gets executed and the event listener called?

Comment: Yes, I added a script that includes src for the js file:
 <script defer src="validate.js"></script>
I'll edit the question.